# Accessing values of a column that are greater than 33, but I also want to be able to access the ID of individuals who have their value greater than 33

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset with a bunch of columns. I have one column titled (rowsums), that are the sums of values in a PTSD questionnaire ( greater than 33 is likely PTSD diagnosis). I want to be able to access rowsums that are greater than 33, while also accessing the respective ID's from the id column to find which participants have scored greater than 33 on a PTSD questionaire, and which ID's correspond to a PTSD diagnosis.

for example if column B has the ID's: N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, etc.
And column M has the values: 20, 45, 21, 58, 12, 62

I use column M to imply that there are several other columns between B and M.

| COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN M |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N1 | 20 |
| 2 | N2 | 45 |
| 3 | N3 | 21 |
| 4 | N4 | 58 |
| 5 | N5 | 12 |
| 6 | N6 | 62 |

I would to extract something that looks like this, returning only the values >33 along with the ID's in column B

| COLUMN B | COLUMN M |
| --- | --- |
| N2 | 45 |
| N4 | 58 |
| N6 | 62 |

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, possibly with some data?

Comment: I posted an example of a table (for research purposes- just want to disclaim that I have not posted any original data in this post, as that is confidential)

Comment: Hi again. I thing that this is a rule written somewhere, about how to ask good questions in SO. Can you provide us with a reproducible example, meaning some code that we can run to get some example data in R, so that you can help those willing to help you? Even a subset of your  data set is fine, or simulated data, or some data set provided in some package. If you are confused, look for "how to ask good questions on SO" on Google, or just have a look at other questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am trying my best. I am very new. Maybe I need to read more documentation. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, with some simulated data as in the tables you provided (omitting COLUMN A since I did not get its purpose in the example):

```
set.seed(1986)

dta = data.frame("columnB" = 1:10, "columnM" = rnorm(10, mean = 33, sd = 2))
your.aim = dta[dta$columnM > 33, ]
```

Basically, I am just subsetting the original data set `dta` by choosing only observations featuring a value for `columnM` (your PTSD rowsums) strictly greater than 33.